# Uniform convergence of a series of functions depending upon a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I'm unable to prove if the following series converge uniformly on $[0,+\infty)$ for the values of the parameter $\beta$ between $2$ and $3$.

$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^\beta x}{x^4+n^4}
$$
The maximum of the summed functions is realized (for fixed $n$) in $\frac{n}{\sqrt[4]{3}}$ and it is $\frac{\sqrt[4]{27}}{4}n^{\beta-3}$
Clearly there is total convergence for $\beta<2$ and there is no convergence if $\beta>3$ except in $x=0$.
For $2<\beta<3$ pointwise convergence holds but not total. How to prove uniform convergence?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x \in [0,\infty)$,

$$\sup_{x \in [0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty\frac{k^\beta x}{x^4+k^4}\right|\geqslant \sup_{x \in [0,\infty)}\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{k^\beta x}{x^4+k^4}\geqslant\sup_{x \in [0,\infty)}  n \cdot \frac{n^\beta x}{x^4 + (2n)^4}\\ \underbrace{\geqslant}_{x = n\in [0,\infty)} n \cdot \frac{n^\beta n}{n^4 + (2n)^4}= \frac{n^{\beta+2}}{17 n^4}= \frac{n^{\beta-2}}{17}$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $\beta \geqslant 2$, the series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$ for $2 < \beta < 3$.